# Needed factory working in angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

Actually i was new to angular js  i am  trying to call my factory operation into controller i dont know where i am going  wrong

and my js goes here

```
app.factory("myFactory",function(){
  var something = {};
  something.getsum = function() {
    $scope.service = " heloo people"
  }
  return something;
});


app.controller("helloController", function($scope,myFactory) {
  $scope.clickme = function() {
    $scope.service=myFactory.getsum();
  }
});
```

and my html goes here

```
<div ng-controller="hello controller">
  <button ng-click="clickme"></button>
  <h2>{{service}}</h2>
</div>
```

and my config goes here:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index/utilise");
   $stateProvider
     .state('index', {
            abstract: true,
            url: "/index",
            templateUrl: "display.html",
              controller:'mainController',
          controllerAs: "parentCtrl",
        })
             .state('index.sample', {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "content/sample.html",

        })
              .state('index.utilise', {
            url: "/utilise",
            templateUrl: "content/utilise.html",

        })
})
```

Comment: please note that $scope not exists in your factory

Comment: then how come i can achieve it

Comment: Pradeep, Alexander Staroselsky has provided almost every solution you asked for. Now, best approach will be is that you provide the plunkr and update the question. Once done, let me know . I'll try to fix that plunkr. Reason being, we cant go into your codebase to debug it, :) . Waiting for your plunkr. Also, attach console error screenshot that you are getting

Comment: Kk Shashank  i will update my plunker today

Comment: @shashankVivek can i give the same info to another controller  like             app.controller("mycontroller", function($scope, myFactory) {

    $scope.service = myFactory.getsum();
  
});

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/EuOjk1eU7ry3hQ87ZYYB?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First issue is that to use the `myFactory` factory in your controller you would need to inject it into the controller via [dependency injection](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di):

```
app.controller("helloController", function($scope, myFactory) {
  $scope.clickme = function() {
    $scope.service = myFactory.getsum();
  }
});
```

Second issue you would not use `$scope` in the `myFactory` factory method `getsum()`, you would simply return the value you need:

```
app.factory("myFactory",function(){
  var something = {};
  something.getsum = function() {
    return " heloo people";
  }
  return something;
});
```

Third issue is `ng-click` was not actually execute controller function `clickme` as there was parenthesis `()` as you would with any JavaScript function. It should be `ng-click="clickme()"` to actually call the function on the controller:

```
<div ng-controller="helloController">
  <button ng-click="clickme()"></button>
  <h2>{{service}}</h2>
</div>
```

Finally, it's unclear what the structure of your application based on the `ui-router` configuration your provided. With `ui-router` you wouldn't really have the need to use `ng-controller` as you can specify what controller any given view should be using. I've created multiple Plunkers, [one](https://plnkr.co/edit/iAYBhhmhwanjkSPEyVjo?p=preview) and [two](https://plnkr.co/edit/X0NPD71Bs9zCOJL4uRH3?p=preview), demonstrating the factory functionality with and without controllers specified for child routes. This should be more than enough to demonstrating calling a controller function in different situations.

Hopefully that helps!